Functional Equation $f(xy+f^2(y))=f(x)f(y)+yf(y)$
How do you solve this problem? I've only managed to prove that $f$ is injective, but that's not enough:

Find all functions $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ for which this equality holds:
$f(xy+f^2(y))=(f(x)+y)f(y), \forall x,y\in(0,\infty)$.

Proof for $f=\text{injective}$:
Let's suppose that there exist $y_1\neq y_2$ for which $f(y_1)=f(y_2)=a\in(0,\infty)$.
For $x\rightarrow y_2, y\rightarrow y_1$ we have $f(y_1y_2+a^2)=a(a+y_1)$, and for $x\rightarrow y_1, y\rightarrow y_2$ we have $f(y_1y_2+a^2)=a(a+y_2)\implies y_1=y_2$, contradiction, so $f=\text{injective}$.

Does the function need to be continuous?

@Marco No, there is nothing more specified.

Ok. Then just look at AOPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1656112

@user26857 My bad, didn't see it on AOPS. Thanks!

it is maybe useful to remark that $$2f(x)=-x+\sqrt{x^2+4f(x^2+f^2(x))}$$

COMMENT.- Suppose $f$ continuous, so for $y=\dfrac 1n$ we have
$$f\left(\frac xn+f^2\left(\frac 1n\right)\right)=\left(f(x)+\frac 1n\right)f\left(\frac1n\right)$$ This expression tends to the form
$$f\left(0+f^2\left(0\right)\right)=\left(f(x)+0\right)f\left(0\right)$$ If $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists then the function $f$ can be extended by continuity and $f(0)$ it has a sens.
But in this situation we would have $f(f(f(0)))=f(0)f(x)$ so $f(x)$ would be constant which leads to an absurde because we would have for  arbitraire $y$, noting $f(x)=c\ne0$ $$c=c^2+cy$$
Thus if $f(x)$ exists it is non continuous of if it is continuous
then  $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Have you read Of mice and men.(John Steinbeck)?
